# Why my website is not showing but my articles are showing in google

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I created a website around 2 months ago, and I have written around 90 articles till now. Most of them are getting indexed in google search.  When I used to search the name of my website it used to appear in the search results below at the end of the page. But, from a week they don't appear in the search results and I have to click on search instead for options to see my website.

If anyone knows why this happens then let me know the solution.

I tried to fix it by adding the url in google search console and it shows that the url is live and is indexed. But, it is still not showing. Also I got a strange Page redirect issue and the page effected was `https://www.mydomain_name.com/` , my actual domain is `https://mydomain_name.com/`

Comment: What do you mean by "the name of my website"? Are you referring to the domain name (or part of)? Or the value of the `title` tag on the homepage? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only presenting the `non-www` urls, then you probably have a redirection somewhere that redirects `www` urls to `non-www` urls.  GSC just presents it to you as redirections. This is normal.

The ordering / ranking of the pages changes not just because of what you may have done to your pages, but also because someone else may have done to their pages.

The best way to see how Google is presenting your pages is to open Google search and use

```
site:mydomain_name
```

Comment: I am not worried about the redirection, my question is that why on searching the name of my website it is not showing, whereas when i search the topic of a an article from the same website it shows the result. And also site:mydomain_name.com shows result.

Comment: Then answer the comment above and add it to your post: "What do you mean by "the name of my website"? Are you referring to the domain name (or part of)? Or the value of the title tag on the homepage? Or something else?"